# android: return to specific Fragment (and pop off everything after it)

Tags: android, android-fragments

Let's say in my app there are a few possible navigation flows (all are `Fragments`)

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
A -> F -> B -> C
```

I'd like to be able to return to fragment `B` regardless of the transaction backstack depth (ie. I don't want to keep track if I'm currently showing `E` or `C`). I noticed it's possible to tag the fragments, but the following  code doesn't seem to work:

In `fragment A` create fragment `B` aka `SocialViewFragment`:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Method 1 
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, frag, SocialViewFragment.FRAG_TAG).commit();

// Method 2
//transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
//transaction.addToBackStack(SocialViewFragment.FRAG_TAG).commit();
```

Then in `Fragment E`, `popBackStack` returns false (and does nothing), cause it can't find the tag?!

```
FragmentManager mgr = PlaybackFrag.this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
if (mgr.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
    // Want to go back to SocialViewFragment !!!    
    mgr.popBackStack(SocialViewFragment.FRAG_TAG, 0); // returns False - can't find the tag!                
}
```

Comment: What does "DOESNT WORK" mean? Does it crash? Does it do anything? Does your LogCat say anything?

Comment: @Tanis.7x neither method adds a fragment with specified tag to the stack. No crashes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you are confusing two different types of tags.

The optional String parameter you can pass to [`add()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) is a tag for the Fragment that allows you to later find the same Fragment by calling `findFragmentByTag()`.

The optional String parameter passed to [`addToBackStack()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) and [`popBackStack()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack(java.lang.String,%20int)) is referred to as a "name" and is used to identify a particular transaction in the FragmentManager's back stack. It is not a Fragment tag because a back stack entry represents a particular transaction that could have multiple Fragment additions or removals.

To utilize the back stack names correctly, make sure you call `addToBackStack()` with a non-null String, then later you can call `popBackStack()` with the same String to pop to that particular transaction.

Also note that in your `add()` call you aren't calling `addToBackStack()` at all. Because of this, `mgr.getBackStackEntryCount()` will be 0 and your `popBackStack()` call will never happen at all (unless you have added other Fragments to the back stack).

Comment: So in other words the `Method 2` should work...but it doesn't! Moreover, with the second method, `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SocialViewFragment.FRAG_TAG);` inside of `Fragment E` returns NULL

Comment: You need to be more descriptive than just "it doesn't work." With the second method, `findFragmentByTag()` *should* return null because as I mentioned in my post the Fragment's tag and the name of the back stack entry are two very different things.

Answer (score 0):

In order to popBackStack you should addToBackStack first.

Use the method that is commented in your code:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
transaction.addToBackStack(SocialViewFragment.FRAG_TAG).commit();
```